# Monkey patching XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open and "touching" arguments

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to monkey patch `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` for an intranet site running in IE8 compatibility mode but it keeps throwing `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method`. The weird thing is... if I "touch" the `arguments` first, i.e. uncomment the `bar`, it works just fine! Does anyone know why and if touching it does actually solve the problem in 100% of cases?

```
var foo = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
  //var bar = arguments;
  foo.apply(this, arguments);
  console.log("OK");
}
```

Here's the IE9 in IE8 mode modern.ie VM screenshot with Google Image search trying to `open` a monkey patched request on scrolling.

[image]

Edit:

```
console.log(foo);
//console.log(foo.apply);
console.log(typeof foo);
console.log(foo instanceof Function);
```

Returns

```
LOG: 
function open() {
    [native code]
}

LOG: object 
LOG: false
```

The `console.log(foo.apply)` one throws `"Object doesn't support this property or method"`.

Funnily enough I cannot replicate this in an actual IE8 VM in any mode I tried, only in IE9 running in IE8 standards mode.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(foo, foo.apply, typeof foo, foo instanceof Function)` maybe? My guess would be that `.apply(this, arguments);` is internally optimized, but "touching" `arguments` *requires* the explicit creation of an arguments object. And as you can see from the possible duplicate that Quentin found, IE is very quirksy about "methods" of plugin objects.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, please see the edit for the log returns.

Comment: Even when *accessing* `.apply` it throws? Wow. But yes, something like this is just what I feared. Does `Function.prototype.apply.call(foo, arguments)` work as a workaround?

Comment: @Bergi sorry, not sure I understand what you're suggesting.  `Function.prototype.apply.call(foo)` does return `Invalid procedure call or argument` so I guess it is being accessed and called, but I'm not sure how to integrate it into `open` patch and pass the original `this` with `arguments` of the `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `thisArg` for apply, it needs to be `Function.prototype.apply.call(foo, <XHR>, arguments)` (where the `<XHR>` is `this` in your example).

Comment: @Bergi getting `SCRIPT5: Invalid procedure call or argument` https://i.imgur.com/vCASEAA.png

Comment: Meh… looks like you need to use an actual wrapper (around whole `XMLHttpRequest` API) if you cannot decorate it :-/

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your help, touching `arguments` it is then. Would've been nice to know the reason behind the magic touch though and `apply` without it.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently saw an example of `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` being overridden, with a slightly different approach than yours;

```
(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        // your special sauce

        open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Can you check and see if doing it this way acts any differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
var XHR = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
XHR.open = function (method, url) {
  //do stuff

  return open.apply(this, arguments);
};
```